# Ruby - Find all records with the same attributes and group them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

### How can I find all records with the same attributes and cluster them together?

Example: table of animal species and their types. I want to cluster same species **IF** they are the same type. Or maybe some other attribute, like color. So if all needed attributes are not the same, I don't want to cluster them.

Best way of showing what I wan't to do is with next example:

```
ID  Species  Type 

0    Bear    Grizzly
1    Wolf    Gray
2    Bear    Grizzly
3    Bear    Polar
4    Wolf    Artic
5    Wolf    Artic
6    Wolf    Gray
```

Needed result:

```
ID  Species  Type      Cluster_id  

0    Bear    Grizzly    1
1    Bear    Grizzly    1
2    Bear    Polar      2
3    Wolf    Artic      3
4    Wolf    Artic      3
5    Wolf    Gray       4
6    Wolf    Gray       4
```

Any ideas how can I write this in ruby?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), which groups all records based on a set of attributes. For example, assuming you have an `Animal` model with `species` and `type` attributes, you can group all records based on similarity in species AND type as follows:

```
Animal.all.group_by { |x| [x.species, x.type] }
```

or, you can first `pluck` the only two attributes needed, and group the resulting array as:

```
Animal.pluck(:species, :type).group_by { |x| [x[0], x[1]] }
```

The result will be a hash of the form:

```
{
    ["Bear", "Grizzly"] => [["Bear", "Grizzly"], ["Bear", "Grizzly"]], 
    ["Wolf", "Gray"]    => [["Wolf", "Gray"], ["Wolf", "Gray"]], 
    ["Bear", "Polar"]   => [["Bear", "Polar"]], 
    ["Wolf", "Artic"]   => [["Wolf", "Artic"], ["Wolf", "Artic"]]
}
```

---

To add the cluster info to each record, consider the following.

If you don't already have the `cluster_id` field created, you can create it using a migration as follows:

```
rails g migration add_cluster_id_to_animals cluster_id:int
rake db:migrate
```

Once you have the `cluster_id` field, you can populate it by iterating over the hash created by `group_by`:

```
hash = Animal.all.group_by { |x| [x.species, x.type] }
hash.each_with_index do |(key,value),index| 
    value.each do |v| 
        v.update_attribute(:cluster_id, index+1)
    end
end
```

or, in one line:

```
Animal.all.group_by { |x| [x.species, x.type] }.each_with_index {|(key,value),index| value.each {|v| v.update_attribute(:cluster_id, index+1)}}
```

---

For example, if initially your records looked as follows:

```
[["Bear", "Grizzly"], 
 ["Wolf", "Gray"], 
 ["Bear", "Grizzly"], 
 ["Bear", "Polar"], 
 ["Wolf", "Artic"], 
 ["Wolf", "Artic"], 
 ["Wolf", "Gray"]]
```

then with `cluster_id` populated, your records will look as follows:

```
[["Bear", "Grizzly", 1], 
 ["Wolf", "Gray",    2], 
 ["Bear", "Grizzly", 1], 
 ["Bear", "Polar",   3], 
 ["Wolf", "Artic",   4], 
 ["Wolf", "Artic",   4], 
 ["Wolf", "Gray",    2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to store the `cluster_id` in the database as mentioned in other answer, you can just populate it for the array being grouped as follows:

Original Array:

```
array = [
  ["Bear", "Grizzly"],
  ["Wolf", "Gray"],
  ["Bear", "Grizzly"],
  ["Bear", "Polar"],
  ["Wolf", "Artic"],
  ["Wolf", "Artic"],
  ["Wolf", "Gray"]
]
```

This can be grouped by species, type with generated `cluster_id` as follows:

```
array.group_by { |x| [x[0], x[1]] }.each.with_index {
  |(key, values), i| values.map! { |x| x << i + 1 }
}
```

The `cluster_id` values will be added to the array & looks like:

```
[
  ["Bear", "Grizzly", 1],
  ["Wolf", "Gray", 2],
  ["Bear", "Grizzly", 1],
  ["Bear", "Polar", 3],
  ["Wolf", "Artic", 4],
  ["Wolf", "Artic", 4],
  ["Wolf", "Gray", 2]
]
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. I will try this too